iOS universal link (applink) opens the app for any path and even for domain itself
I am facing one weird issue in universal link. Here is my implementation.
let suppose these are the details.
AppId (TeamId) - ASDFASDF
Domain Name -- com.demo.ios.app
path -- /login
Here is my apple-app-site-association file content
{
  "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "ASDFASDF.com.demo.ios.app"
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "/login",
            "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /login"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Here is the entitlement I have added under Associated Domains in the xcode
applinks:com.demo.ios.app

Here is my expectation, let's assume the app is installed -

https://com.demo.ios.app/login --> On tap of this link my app should open.
https://com.demo.ios.app/login/ --> On tap of this link safari app should open, because there is extra / at end of path.
https://com.demo.ios.app/ --> On tap of this link safari app should open, because there is no matching path.
https://com.demo.ios.app --> On tap of this link safari app should open, because there is no matching path.

What is happening ? the issue I am facing --
For each link the app is getting opened. I want to restrict this behaviour

Have you used the universal link tests under the developer menu on your phone?  Have you updated your ASAA file from an original version? If so, are you using developer mode to bypass the apple CDN. Use a sysdiagnose to get the universal link config

@Paulw11 I followed multiple ways to fix it, but I failed in each. Do you have any reference or can you share more details on what you are suggesting ?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3155-debugging-universal-links
